# Can JavaScript force different sessions per tab?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

My company's web app maintains sessions via cookies. One of our customers uses MS Edge and wants to be able to have a completely separate session running our web app in each browser tab, for sometimes 2 but up to 3 tabs and 3 separate sessions.

As a workaround, getting 2 different sessions is pretty easy by using 1 normal Edge window + 1 private/incognito window. The 2 sessions are separate and that's what they want. But what if they want 3 tabs and 3 sessions? Is there a way with JavaScript to force the browser (in this case Edge) to not share cookies between tabs, and thus force a separate session in each tab? I'd prefer not to have to rely on Private/Incognito usage, though that is the workaround for now.

Note: This is a .NET webapp and I am aware of the `cookieless` setting in web.config - apparently that approach doesn't fully work (I don't yet have the details why), which is why I'm feeling out a possible js approach.

Comment: No. Browsers assume (other than the "private" case you noted) that it's a *feature* for cookies to be shared from the same browser process to the same domain. You can start separate browser processes, but users won't know how to do that, and even the private browsing trick is going to be a usability fail in all likelihood.

Comment: I'm not the best person to answer about this, but I'd say that's not possibile if the sessions rely on cookies. You could achieve a session separation if you track them via some id in the URL, then managed (in some way) server-side.

Comment: related - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/open-a-new-session-in-edge/4f1f56ff-54ce-405e-808b-8c6131afa69a

Comment: Now, you could potentially make an explicit hook for a user to (for example) click a navigation link and then your own software can maintain a separate token somehow to keep track of parallel pseudo-sessions in different tabs. That doesn't sound easy but I think it's possible.

Comment: Maybe you can try something with services workers. Since it acts as proxy for all requests, and since service workers may be used to sync tabs, maybe you can do the opposite : differenciate requests cookies depending of the tab. I don't have time to provide you a PoC, but I'm pretty sure you can achieve something like that. It may be slightly hacky... But since your client request is non conventional.. I think it may worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. There is no notion of "sessions" in cookies. Cookies are always browser-wide, shared by all tabs. Even so-called "session cookies" (= cookies which die when the user closes the browser) are browser-wide.

For an alternative, look at the [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) API. This *does* work the way you need: it creates a separate session for each tab, even if it's the same URL.